# Issue where android downloads folder different in the files app then what is read pragmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

When I go to print out the names of all the files in my downloads folder I see 4 of the 25+ files on my device print in console.

code

```
 val downloadsFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        val toslist = downloadsFolder.listFiles()

        toslist?.forEach { file ->
            val cellValue = file.name
            print("$cellValue \n")
        }
```

I have a pixel 5 running android 12 and downloaded the excel file off a gmail attachment. In the files app on my phone the excel file is in the downloads folder. Not sure why I can not read it there pragmatically. Pragmatically I can only see images I downloaded off my text messenger app.

Anyone have any idea what is happening or where this file might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android 11+ devices you will only see the files created by your app itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the code where you are reading the data programmatically.
It might be the case that you have the open document to only search for images.
If yes you also have to add the .xlsx extension to the

```
private val loadMediaWithDocuments =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) { result ->
    //handle the result
    }

Then use this 
loadMediaWithDocuments.launch(
            arrayOf(
                "image/*",
                "video/*",
                "application/pdf",
                "text/plain" // add the desired extension of the file type you want to 
                              //see with OpenDocument activity result contrat
            )
```